# OS X Preview unable to open GeoTiff due to error 259?

Tags: geotiff-tiff, osx

I'm currently working on a GeoTiff writer which writes GeoTiffs to the file system. I can write the GeoTiff, dump it with **tiffdump**, **listgeo** and **gdalinfo** and my own GeoTiff reader can read it with no problems. The cell type is *Double* (float 64 bits) and it works well.

I'm running OS X and there we have a program called *Preview* which is like a basic image viewer. I guess all of you know which program I'm talking about. This program can't (!) open my GeoTiff, and the OS X logs says nothing at all, except that the error code is 259.

Here I have a link to the file:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/42266515/float.tif

It even works in Dropbox preview so maybe it's just Preview acting weird. I can also say that if I use integers instead of floats for the image Preview can show it.

I would love for someone to find an error with the file, so I can fix the writer and be able to read it with Preview.

It has nothing to do with the size of the image, I created a 200*200 pixel image which Preview didn't open either.

Comment: I do not see any problems with this raster when I view it in ArcMap.  Looks like it is a 64-bit float with 2 columns and 2 rows with a cell size of 10m.  The location is east of Birmingham, AL.

Comment: Do you know if Preview supports tiffs which use Float 64 data type? Make a series of test images with gdal_translate with different -ot parameters http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html. If you find that Preview simply does not support Float64 then you can try to contact Apple and make a feature request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your GeoTIFF file. You just need a better program to view it with.

Most basic "paint"-style programs such as Preview, Paint, Paint.NET, all expect a Byte pixel type for TIFF files. Although a float type is part of the file specifications, most software don't implement this support. Software that should work include most GIS software, and advanced image software like GIMP.

Comment: Thanks! I have been able to view all other tiffs I worked with in Preview so I thought it would be a good test. But now I know thats not the case.